# Swagger codegen - is it possible to change generated method parameter name?

Tags: spring, kotlin, swagger, swagger-codegen

I have a timezone offset header parameter in my contract:

```
parameters:
    - $ref: "#/components/parameters/timezoneOffset"


...


timezoneOffset:
      in: header
      name: X-Timezone-Offset
      required: true
      schema:
        type: integer
        format: int64
```

When generating code with swagger codegen, the parameter in method name is called `xminusTimezoneMinusOffset`.

```
@RequestHeader(value="X-Timezone-Offset", required=true) xminusTimezoneMinusOffset: kotlin.Long
```

That looks pretty bad and I would like it to be generated with let's say `timezoneOffset` variable name. Is it possible to do so?